# Select product with properties by group

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Product table:

```
id
1
2
3
```

Product properties

```
product_id   prop_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            2
2            3
3            1   
4            2
5            1
5            3
```

Props has groups. Ex, prop_id (1, 2) is a group #1, prop_id (3) - group #2.
I need to select product which contains one prop from group #1 and one from group #2.

Like this

```
select * from product_properties WHERE prop_id IN (1, 2) AND prop_id IN (3)
```

But it`s doesn't work, how to create similar correct query?

That query must return me products with id 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.prop_id, b.prop_id
FROM product_properties a, product_properties b
WHERE 
    a.product_id=b.product_id AND 
    a.prop_id IN (1, 2) AND 
    b.prop_id = 3
```

Comment: If I have more than 2 property groups query will looks like this:

`SELECT *        
FROM product_property_params a, product_property_params b,    
product_property_params c  
WHERE 
    a.product_id=b.product_id AND 
    a.product_id=c.product_id AND 
    a.param_id IN (23, 24) AND 
    c.param_id = 26 AND
    b.param_id = 27
`

Comment: how do you know which properties belong to which group?

Comment: I have 3rd table with props groups, but relation 'prop with product' realised by the table Product properties.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_properties
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN prop_id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 END) > 0 -- mean have at least one property with 1 or 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN prop_id = 3       THEN 1 END) = 1 -- mean has property 3
```

This assume a product cant have same property more than once.

Comment: no, isnt. But you should try explain plan and see if need index for `product_id`

Comment: my orm doesn't accept WHEN in having, there is other way?

Comment: what you mean ORM? that is standard SQL.

Comment: I'm writing this in php using framework (which include own ORM)   
    `$builder->having('COUNT(CASE WHEN Common\Models\ProductPropertyParams.param_id IN (23, 24) THEN 1 END) > 0');`

and in result CASE clauses are not supported. In support forum they recommend to replace cause with if.